# Synchronizing two noisy sinusoids out of phase

Tags: python, scipy, signals, signal-processing

I currently have two noisy sinusoids which are out of phase and I am looking for a solution to set them in phase. Firstly, I was trying to just adjust the sinusoids via finding the zero-crossing values with an upward trend, however, as there is some noise in the signal, this solution is not suitable. I made a small mock-up example:

```
time = np.arange(0, 60, 0.005)
amp = 2
F = 0.25
signal1 = amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*F*time + np.pi)
signal2 = amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*F*time + np.pi/3)

mu, sigma = 0.2, 0.1 # mean and standard deviation
noise1 = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, len(signal1))
noise2 = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, len(signal2))


noisy_signal1 = signal1 + noise1
noisy_signal2 = signal2 + noise2

plt.figure()
plt.plot(time, noisy_signal1)
plt.plot(time, noisy_signal2)
plt.show()
```

Of course that in reality, I don't know which is the phase shift, but I do know the amplitude and the frequency of each sinusoidal beforehand. What I want to achieve, is to go from the plots you can see when running the code, to this:
[image]

EDIT1: Using the correlation function might be a suitable solution. However, you will have the problem that since the signal is noisy, the maximum correlation could be found in several periods ahead of one of the signals, and therefore, losing a lot of data points when doing the shift. I am looking specially for a solution in which I am identifying the phase and just shifting one of the sinuoids.

Comment: I updated the answer. If the frequency is known or calculated, then all that's required is to  remove the number of samples corresponding to the modulus of the maximum position and the number of samples in one cycle.

Comment: Updated again to use the results of the FFT that was used to calculate the frequency to also provide the phase difference, which will be several orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for asking this question. I'm looking into applications of cross-correlation and this was my first try at writing some code.

Cross-correlation repeatedly convolves two signals and provides a (long) array as output, each expressing how well correlated the two signals are at any given time difference. For sinusoidal signals like yours a few cycles would probably be sufficient rather than correlating the entire array, and decimation might also be reasonable to improve execution time. Also I'm using the numpy correlate function rather than the scipy one, the latter using FFTs to work faster on large arrays. This should be a fascinating area of exploration.

To shift the phase of the second signal, first the signals are cross-correlated, then I find the point with the maximum value. The second array is rotated by the index of that maximum value to synchronize the the two arrays so that they have maximum correlation. Rotation assumes full cycles so shifting and filling with zeroes would be more universal.

It's just 3 lines of code (numpy is wonderful), inserted right before the plot. There may be edge cases I haven't thought about, but this works exactly the way you wanted it.

```
corr = np.correlate(noisy_signal1, noisy_signal2, 'full')
corr_max_idx = np.argmax(corr)
noisy_signal2 = np.roll(noisy_signal2, corr_max_idx)
```

To get a very similar result losing less than a half cycle, you just need to find the remainder of the argmax calculation when dividing by the frequency in samples. We know what the frequency is from your example program, but I calculate it anyway using FFT. While FFT isn't the recommended way of calculating a single frequency, I found the signal too noisy to reliably calculate from zero crossings, as there are several per cycle.

Here's what I came up with. I changed a bit of the example code so the sample rate is available to me for later, although I ended up not needing it.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import fft
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

sr = 200
time = np.arange(0, 60, 1/sr)

amp = 2
F = 0.25
omega = 2 * np.pi * F

signal1 = amp*np.sin(omega * time + np.pi)
signal2 = amp*np.sin(omega * time + np.pi/3)

mu, sigma = 0.2, 0.1 # mean and standard deviation
noise1 = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, len(signal1))
noise2 = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, len(signal2))


noisy_signal1 = signal1 + noise1
noisy_signal2 = signal2 + noise2

# Get frequency in samples
fft1 = fft.fft(noisy_signal1)
fft2 = fft.fft(noisy_signal2)
max_f = np.argmax(np.abs(fft1))
f = len(noisy_signal1) / max_f

# Perform correlation to determine best fit for phase difference (in samples)
corr = np.correlate(noisy_signal1, noisy_signal2, 'full')
delta_p = int(round(np.argmax(corr) % f))

# Chop phase difference (maximum 1/2 cycle)
fi = int(round(f,0))
if delta_p < fi/ 2:
    noisy_signal1 = noisy_signal1[delta_p:]
    noisy_signal2 = noisy_signal2[:-delta_p]
    time = time[delta_p:]
else:
    noisy_signal1 = noisy_signal1[:delta_p - fi]
    noisy_signal2 = noisy_signal2[fi - delta_p:]
    time = time[:delta_p - fi]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(time, noisy_signal1)
plt.plot(time, noisy_signal2)
plt.show()
```

To get rid of correlation, which is computationally expensive, we can also use the FFT that was used to calculate the frequency, changing the two lines for the correlation to:

```
# Do the same calculation with the FFT
p1 = np.angle(fft1[max_f])
p2 = np.angle(fft2[max_f])
delta_p = int((f * ((p2 - p1) / (2 * np.pi))) % f)
```

Another possibility that requires neither correlation or FFT, if the frequency is known, is to use a single bin FFT then measure the difference between the phase angles to get the phase difference, e.g.

```
mix = np.exp(-1j * omega * time)
p1 = np.angle(noisy_signal1 * mix)
p2 = np.angle(noisy_signal2 * mix)
delta_p = int((f * (np.mean(p2 - p1) / (2 * np.pi))) % f)
```

Comment: Re-reading your question, where you say the amplitude and frequency (and presumably sample rate) are known in advance, the last method would be the best, as it will be the fastest to execute.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But the main point of the question would be exactly how to translate that phase different to shift the sinusoids

Comment: That's exactly what the code does! It shifts one of the two to overlap the other. The output is exactly like your picture. What else do you need? To be clear - delta_p is the number of samples, always less than 1 cycle, that the two signals are out of phase. If delta_p is less than half a cycle samples are removed from noisy signal 1, otherwise from noisy signal 2. In the case of 1/4 Hz & 200 samples/sec, that is a maximum of 399 samples removed. And the section under the comment "Chop phase difference" is what actually shifts one sinusoid to be in phase with the other.

Comment: I'd recommend the following. If the frequency is known, just use the 4 lines in the last section (single bin DFT) to calculate the phase, and then use delta_p to slice as shown in the "chop" section, or just shift one signal and fill with zeros (leaving time alone). If the frequency is not known, use the frequency information from the FFT to find the frequency with the greatest amplitude, then use the corresponding phase information to do the shift.

Comment: Beaware that, FFT to discover the phase only if FFT size corresponds to an integer number of periods.

Comment: @Bob yes that is correct. Thinking this problem through has helped me in the design of a  radio direction finder program I've been working on. Specifically the DFT has provided some simplification and faster execution than zero crossing or FFT approaches.